# Data is not going into database during loop

Tags: php, mysql, html, dom, loops

I have written below to extract data from webpage, but this is running continuously with out inserting data into table.  How do I split this trancation in below code.

I want to insert for each url immediately and commit in loop. This is not working:

```
<?php
// example of how to use basic selector to retrieve HTML contents
ini_set('log_errors','0');
ini_set('display_errors','1');
error_reporting(2047);
include('simple_html_dom.php');
include('parameters.php');
// get DOM from URL or file

set_time_limit(0);
$site_name="sitename";
mysql_connect($hostname, $user, $pass) or
                die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database);
$query="select site_name,category,subcategory,link,first_no,last_no 
        from `search_links` where site_name='".$site_name."'";

echo $query;
$res=mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) 
{      
    $links[]=array(
        "site_name"=>$row["site_name"],
        "category"=>$row["category"],
        "subcategory"=>$row["subcategory"],
        "url"=>$row["link"],
        "first_no"=>$row["first_no"],
        "last_no"=>$row["last_no"]);    
}

foreach ($links as $link)    
{
    for ($i=$link["first_no"];$i<$link["last_no"];$i++)
    {
        try 
        {
            $html = file_get_html($link["url"].$i);    
            $sql = array();
            foreach($html->find('a') as $e)
            {
                $sql[] = "('".$e->href."',
                    '".$site_name."',
                    '".$link["category"]."',
                    '".$link["subcategory"]."','N')";
            }
            #var_dump($sql);
            mysql_connect($hostname, $user, $pass) or
                die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db($database);

            $sql_ext=" ON DUPLICATE KEY update duplicate='Y'";
        /*//echo('INSERT INTO table (link,site,category,subcategory, archived) 
            VALUES '.implode(',', $sql));*/
            mysql_query(
                'INSERT INTO classifieds (link,site,category,subcategory, archived)
                VALUES '.implode(',', $sql).$sql_ext);    
            mysql_query("COMMIT");
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you please improve your code formatting? It's hard to see what belongs to what with that messed up indentation. Also, possibly cut that code down to only the relevant parts?

Comment: code & query look ok, `COMMIT` is unnecessary (as you didn't `BEGIN` any transaction), what's the result of `mysql_query('INSERT...')`? what's the schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql extension does not throw exceptions.
so, either use regular error reporting

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO classifieds (link,site,category,subcategory, archived)
        VALUES '.implode(',', $sql).$sql_ext;
mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$sql);
```

or throw an exception this way

```
if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
   throw new Exception(mysql_error().$sql); 
}
```